# One of my users can't login to mediawiki (LDAP-Backend)

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running Mediawiki 1.26.2 on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and have configured it to use LDAP as backend. The current installation is a made of a backup of an old version which ran on an old version of OpenSuse without the LDAP backend. For all my users everything is working fine - just one is having problems when he tries to login. Here comes the error message:

```
Interner Fehler

[2f7bcd76] /mediawiki/index.php?title=Spezial:Anmelden&action=submitlogin&type=login&returnto=Hauptseite MWException from line 3701 of /var/www/html/wikiHHG/includes/User.php: CAS update failed on user_touched for user ID '73' (read from slave); the version of the user to be saved is older than the current version.

Backtrace:

#0 /var/www/html/mediawiki/extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php(1244): User->saveSettings()
#1 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specials/SpecialUserlogin.php(830): LdapAuthenticationPlugin->updateUser(User)
#2 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specials/SpecialUserlogin.php(958): LoginForm->authenticateUserData()
#3 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specials/SpecialUserlogin.php(341): LoginForm->processLogin()
#4 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(384): LoginForm->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(553): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(281): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#7 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(714): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#8 /var/www/html/mediawiki/includes/MediaWiki.php(508): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/html/mediawiki/index.php(41): MediaWiki->run()
#10 {main}
```

Is there a way to rewrite the information of the user (seems to be a date problem) so that he can login again?

Thanks Scroom

Comment: this question should be in Ask Ubuntu, not here

Comment: Thought that this a mediawiki question and followed the link in the mediawiki documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. In the user table of the wiki-db (MySQL) there has been no entry for user_touched for the user where the login didn't work. So I've set a random date by doing:

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET user_touched = '20160409104704' WHERE user_name = 'Username';
```

and the login for this user worked as expected!

Comment: Thx - very nice workaround. I wonder why the Wikimedians have so much trouble with this issue since many months.